# SSH shuts down with broken pipe before python program finishes matplotlib part

Tags: python, matplotlib, ssh

I am running a python 3 program via SSH which takes a few hours to finish. After all computations the program should save a matplotlib figure and then stop. What happens is that after all computations a Write failed: broken pipe error is shown and when I log back in the figure is not updated.

Another question mentioned the process spawns child processes for the figure which might be killed when the main program finishes computation, so I ran it with nohup to no avail. What other options can I try out?

Comment: are there logs your program spitting out? which might give some clues?

Comment: What shell are you using on the remote machine? If it's just bash, all processes spawned will be killed (if you are not doing anything specifically to prevent that). Personally, I use tmux or byobu on remote machines for that reason (you just detach from those sessions, and then re-attach when you log back in).

Comment: Another possibility is that you are using an interactive backend in matplotlib, and drawing the figures fails because there are no display settings when you are logged out / the display settings have changed when you log back in. Try using the `Agg` backend.

Comment: The only log it gives is the write failed: broken pipe error.
I am using normal bash and interactive mode, I will try the other options!

Answer (score 0):

If I had a guess here, it is that your SSH TCP connection is getting dropped.  On my systems, I set the following SSH client parameters to help in this situation.

```
ServerAliveInterval = 300
ServerAliveCountMax = 300
```

This keeps data flowing over your connection even while your terminal is awaiting output from the running process.